# El Capitan, expand desktop thumbnails by default in Mission Control

Tags: mission-control, macos

On previous versions of OS X, desktop thumbnails were showing by default in the Mission control.

In El Capitan, however, they are collapsed by default and only the names are showing (i.e., Desktop1, Desktop2, etc.). I have to place the mouse pointer onto them to expand it and see the thumbnails.

Is there any way I can get the previous behaviour back?

Comment: Please submit feedback to apple, as this is very annoying.

Comment: I have been a beta tester of El Capitan, and I submitted a feedback months ago. Basically I told them there should be an option to choose  expanded/collapsed by default. I am on the GM, and I cannot find any such option. So I posted this to find out if there was any hack.

Comment: I did too, and I hope when it's released, someone can find a hack.

Comment: Submitted feedback to Apple about this. It's a minor annoyance, but I use Mission Control so often, it ends up driving me crazy. It's like slowly getting poked to death.

Comment: I had tried Sierra first public beta; no change. I think Apple will never change this no matter how much we say no.

Answer (score 31):

**Edit 1/30/16**:
After using a few different options in my daily workflow over the past few months, I've settled on almost exactly the solution proposed by @Arctus. Despite requiring a 3rd-party program, [BetterTouchTool](http://www.bettertouchtool.net/) (BTT), I believe it to be the best current option.

See @Arctus's [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/212213/154633) for the general method and a helpful screenshot. Here are the specifics that were missing from that post:

- You want to make sure that you have the mission control gesture turned on in your system preferences and set to either a 3- or 4-finger swipe up (the only options). (I tried adding a step to my BTT macro to open mission control, but I abandoned that because you lose the ability to use the inverse gesture, a 3- or 4-finger swipe down, to *close* Mission Control.)
- For the "Delay Next Action" step, you'll most likely need to set it to at least 0.06 seconds. I settled on 0.08 seconds. (I tried shorter durations like 0.02 and 0.03 seconds, but they didn't work consistently. It seems that sometimes that was too fast so it didn't trigger the expansion. YRMV on this, so if it's not working for you, or if it only works sometimes, try increasing this a bit.)
- For the "Move Mouse To" step, I found best results using the exact top-middle of my screen. (ex: My screen width is 1280 pixels, so I used x=640, y=0.)

You'll probably notice that BTT actually has a predefined action called "Mission Control & Immediately Show Desktop Previews". Unfortunately, it has an annoyingly long delay between opening mission control and expanding the desktop previews that made it unusable for me. This custom solution is very smooth, very consistent, and doesn't seem to cause any undesired behavior.

The other main variation of the BetterTouchTool method is to use either the top-left or top-right hot-corners to open mission control and then to use BTT to move your mouse to the corner and back upon your chosen gesture. This allows other gestures besides 3- or 4-finger swipe up, but it introduces a hot corner that you may not want. I found that I was triggering the hot corner accidentally far too often for this to be a viable option for me. Again, YRMV.

I'm not an expert at BTT by any means, but if anyone has any questions, I'm happy to try to help. Good luck!

**/edit**

---

**Original Post:**

### El Capitan Mission Control Mechanics

As [Fletcher91 mentioned](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/208594/154633), thumbnails are collapsed by default if you launch Mission Control from a "Desktop Space" (a Space with a name like "Desktop 1", "Desktop 4", etc.) whereas the thumbnails are *expanded* by default if you launch Mission Control from a "Fullscreen App Space" (a Space that was generated by fullscreen-ing a window and that is named for that app window, like "Notes" or the title of a webpage if it's a browser window).

The reason for this is that Mission Control serves two functions:

1. Display all open windows in your *current* Desktop Space to enable easy switching between them (the "all-open-windows" view).
2. Display the list of all Spaces to enable easy switching between them.

An Apple rep I spoke to told me that that the motivation behind collapsing the thumbnails when opening Mission Control from a Desktop Space was to provide more screen real-estate to the *all-open-windows* view and to reduce clutter. When opening Mission Control from a Fullscreen App Space, the focus changes to the *all-open-windows* view for the *most recently viewed Desktop Space* and the thumbnails are expanded (unfounded speculation: presumably this is because for Fullscreen App Spaces, there *are* no other windows in the same Space, so the only reason to open Mission Control would be to switch Spaces).

---

### Any way to always show thumbnails by default?

The Apple rep also confirmed that **there is currently no way to enable thumbnail expansion by default**.

However, I did some research and tested out a few other answers and I've been able to confirmed some special cases that may be useful:

1. If you use "Hot Corners" `System Preferences >> Mission Control` and set either the top-left or top-right corners to open Mission Control, it *simulates* the old behavior, but only because in triggering the Hot Corner callback, you've placed your mouse within the area that triggers the thumbnail expansion anyway). Unfortunately, this is probably the best option at this point, even though it involves changing a habit which isn't always easy. If you go with this approach, I recommend disabling the trackpad gesture so that this is the *only* way you can do it—at least until the habit sinks in.
2. As [akaRem mentioned](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/208859/154633), **if you open enough Spaces, Mission Control thumbnails will be expanded by default!** I tested this on my 13" 2013 MBP Retina using all fullscreen Chrome Spaces, all desktop Spaces, and various combinations of the two along with some other random Spaces (including the Dashboard Space both on and off) and it always took exactly 13 spaces to make it so that the thumbnails were expanded by default when opening Mission Control from a Desktop Space, which is a different number from **akaRem**. I don't know if it varies with hardware or what, but it's interesting. (If anyone else tests this, let me know your results). Ultimately though, this is not a practical solution.
3. The closest thing to a usable workaround that we have at this point (if you want to open Mission Control with gestures or hotkeys) is to use third-party software like [BetterTouchTool](http://www.bettertouchtool.net/) to create a macro that executes on your chosen gesture [like Arctus's did](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/212213/154633).

Like others here, I have submitted feedback to Apple for this issue. [Here's the link](http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html) if you want to do the same.

Comment: +1!  Top-quality answer.  Well written, well organized, and useful links.  …(Unfortunately, it also makes me sad! ☹)

Comment: Thanks @Zearin. I actually just added a new section at the top with my updated recommendation. It's pretty seamless once you have it set up. You may want to give it a shot. I echo your sentiments though. It's pretty disappointing that this kind of a workaround is necessary. Definitely a regression in user experience.

Comment: BTT became paid a few months ago.

Comment: The problem with BTT is it is slow! It takes another half a second and sometimes it jiggles your cursor. Extremely annoying when you are in the flow trying to do something quickly :(

Comment: Apple's feeback link was changed to https://www.apple.com/feedback/macos.html – would be great if you could update your answer @Sherlock_HJ!

Comment: This is currently broken in v2.340 of BTT. The creator is working on a fix. https://github.com/fifafu/BetterTouchTool/issues/2080

Comment: I opened the maximum of 16 spaces, and they still not expand by default. Maybe it only works if your monitor is not big enough. I'm on a 2560x1080 so even with 16 theres still space left on either side

Comment: Sorry for commenting 6 years late, but I'm using macOS Ventura and BTT. The Built-in Mission Control and Immediately Show... option works very well for me. Maybe they worked out the lag issue.

Answer (score 24):

Yes, this is very annoying
I submitted feedback at
http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html

I suggest everyone who agrees does the same as this is either a bug or design regression.

Comment: @Tetsujin I disagree with your comment. This answer states plainly that this is a bug. It's not the answer the OP wanted, but it is an answer.

Comment: I don't think it is a bug; probably Apple thought program title texts were as intuitive as the thumbnails of the programs. But alas, to me and many people, a picture is worth a thousand words. I had also submitted a suggestion about adding IME icons in the IME switcher popup (Command + Space long press), as it currently only shows IME name texts.

Comment: I like your suggestion that frustrated users take to the feedback form. I've joined you there.

Comment: I just submitted feedback a moment ago.  I just upgraded and I'm pissed.  I regularly use MC to see what screen I want to go to and then use 3-finger swipe to quickly get there based on visual feedback at the top of the screen.  Now I have to manually move my mouse to the top of the screen.  So unbelievably annoying!

Comment: it simply needs a settings option. if you like it one way or the other, be able to specify which behavior you want. not everything has to be one-size-fits-all

Comment: The Link is broken

Answer (score 13):

A work around I have is to set a hot corner to the top left to open mission control. That way, when I open mission control via this, they are already expanded.

This still works, but [bettertouchtools 1.24](http://www.bettertouchtool.net/) has added a show mission control and immediately show desktop previous which works pretty much perfectly.

Comment: Only if you use the top corners

Comment: Unfortunately version in version 1.27 of bettertouchtools this feature is not working for me. It seems bugged, because all windows jiggle a little bit (just a few pixels), when I do the "Two Finger Double-Tap" :(

Comment: I am using v1.27 and it's working great for me.

Comment: it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Bettertouchtools for the win, a little bouncy, but better than nothing

Comment: Note: BBT wont work if you leave the osx gesture active.

Comment: works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 13):

Developer Brian Kendall has created this for restoring the old behaviour: https://github.com/briankendall/forceFullDesktopBar

It injects code into the Dock process to call the method that shows mission control with the `showFullBar`parameter set to `true`. So while it's a hack, it's a pretty clean one that works well for all the different ways to activate mission control (e.g., I use a keyboard shortcut, 2-finger tap on magic mouse, and 3-finger swipe up on trackpad).

It's puzzling why Apple didn't include this setting as a preference when it's that simple.

Comment: Unfortunately, from the README: "forceFullDesktopBar does not currently work with macOS Sierra. Though I am trying to figure out how to update it, there's a good chance I never will be able to. The Dock in 10.12 has been significantly rewritten in Swift, and the convenient Objective-C methods that were easy to extract from its binary and had clearly readable names and arguments are now gone, replaced with functions that have no symbol at all."

Comment: This broke after El Capitan but there is a new program from the same author: see my [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/318066/279828).

Comment: For those still reading, I've updated forceFullDesktopBar to work in macOS 10.13 and 10.14.

Comment: This is brilliant, and currently (January 2023) does work with all macOS versions, except for the latest beta version.

Answer (score 12):

I managed to get around this for the time being using BetterTouchTools. Specifically I've set my 3 finger swipe gesture to move the mouse to the top of the screen and back again. It's seamless enough that I don't see the mouse actually move so it'll do for now.

[image: BetterTouchTool Trackpad Gesture]

Meanwhile I too have submitted feedback to Apple about this change.

It does seem like they're pushing everyone to use their fullscreen feature which does automatically expand the spaces bar when Mission Control is opened from a fullscreen application/desktop. But many of us BetterTouchTool users specifically don't like the way OSX's fullscreen feature operates and therefore don't use it.

If there were an option for the default fullscreen feature to always show and not hide the OSX menu bar I'd probably get used to it. Options are good :)

Comment: yeah I agree that people really probably didn't need that extra 40 pixels of vertical space in mission control. The downsides of the annoyance of having desktops move when you hover over them is greater than the upsides of extra mission control space imo. I'msure 95% of people would agree. They need to just allow an option to toggle this in mission control preferences. done deal. Insert a boolean. wrap the code around an if-else statement. Make another config checkbox. done.

Comment: BTT now has a specific action called "Mission Control & Immediately Show Desktop Previews", so there's no need for the macro anymore ;)

Answer (score 4):

Although BetterTouchTool (BTT) now has the "Mission Control & Immediately Show Desktop Previews" action that you can assign to a trackpad gesture, there is an annoying delay between when mission control starts and when the desktop previews are displayed.

I've stumbled onto a macro similar to, but slightly different from the one suggested by @Arctus, that gets me back to nearly the same behavior as in Yosemite.

**Step one** is to enable the upper left "hot corner" to show mission control.

[image]

**Step two** is the following macro in BTT:

[image: BTT macro]

EDIT: You also have to have the standard trackpad mission control gesture set for either three or four finger swipe up (doesn't seem to matter which).

[image]

Comment: The behaviour might have changed now as it is pretty much instant!

Answer (score 3):

Playing around, I've learned that thumbnails are only displayed when the user switches to mission control while having a full screen app active.

If you use multiple monitors, all the screens must have an application running in full screen mode enabled.

So for the time being, try to have a full screen app on all monitors.

Comment: I tried. It only showed thumbnails when I swipe up from a full screen application. It did not show thumbnails even if there was a full screen app, if I swipe up from another app.

Comment: True, When on any desktop, all spaces are collapsed. When on full-screen app, all spaces are expanded. Not sure about multimonitor, but on built-in this works like this.

Answer (score 3):

I found some kind of workaround.
When you have lots of spaces they will be shown as expanded thumbnails even if Mission Control is launched from regular Desktop.

For example, on my MacBook Pro 13, when I have 1 Desktop + 7 Fullscreen Safari or 3 Desktop + 6 Fullscreen Safari, then everything is shown like before.

Answer (score 3):

A friend of mine who has the 10.11.4 beta said this implementation is coming back. It would be nice if they made this a preference. Here is the screenshot he sent me:

[image: Mission Control Thumbnails]

**Edit:** This information is incorrect. Mission control shows thumbnails instantly when there is a large number of spaces.

Comment: Oh, that is good. Finally, Apple listened to users.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Unfortunately though, your friend may be mistaken. This screenshot has many spaces (aka "desktops") open (17 of them). As I described in my answer (and as was originally pointed out by @akaRem) if you have more than a certain number of spaces open at any one time (13 spaces was the cutoff in my tests) the desktop previews appear automatically upon activating mission control. So the behavior your firend is experiencing could be due to that effect. Could you have your friend test again with only 2 or 3 spaces open and see what happens? Thanks.

Comment: @Sherlock_HJ You are correct. My friend is mistaken.

Answer (score 3):

*Sierra/High Sierra update*

To follow up on [Kevin C.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/38315/kevin-c)'s [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/229149/279828), the author of forceFullDesktopBar has created a new version, https://github.com/briankendall/missionControlFullDesktopBar, which works on 10.12+. It was a bit involved to install but works great for me -- the only solution I've found that has **no delay at all!**

Setup steps:

1. Disable the Mission Control gesture in `System Preferences -> Trackpad`.
2. Clone the missionControlFullDesktopBar repository

   - `git clone https://github.com/briankendall/missionControlFullDeskopBar`
3. Open `missionControlFullDeskopBar.xcodeproj` in Xcode.
4. Build the project (⌘B).
5. Find out where it went by checking `File -> Project Settings...`. On my machine it's `~/Library/Developer Tools/Xcode/DerivedData`. And there will be a folder in there that starts with the project name (e.g., `missionControlFullDeskopBar-cjhllkdjkhncuzglpiezmyqmdufu`).
6. In BetterTouchTool, bind your Mission Control shortcut to `Execute Shell Script / Task`. As the `Launch Path`, enter the *full path* to the compiled executable: `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/missionControlFullDesktopBar-cjhllkdjkhncuzglpiezmyqmdufu/Build/Products/Debug/missionControlFullDesktopBar.app/Contents/MacOS/missionControlFullDesktopBar` (adjust if your paths are different). As `Parameter`, enter `-d -i`.

   [image: BetterTouchTool shell command detail]

   Optional: bind another shortcut for dismissing Mission Control. I was used to the four-finger swipe down to dismiss, but disabling the four-finger swipe up in System Preferences got rid of this. As quick fix, I bound four-finger swipe down to Escape in BTT. Full BTT setup:

   [image: BetterTouchTool shortcut setup]

Answer (score 2):

Okay guys, I have a quick workaround for High Sierra that will restore the old behavior without third party tools, or gestures that don't feel right. HOWEVER, you'll need to be connected to an external monitor. Here's what you do:

1) In Preferences>Mission Control, turn on "Displays Have Separate Spaces" (I don't know if this is necessary, but I'd have to log-out to test this)

2) On the external monitor, fullscreen whichever app you have on there

3) Tada! Now all your monitors' spaces are expanded into thumbnail view by default, even the ones with only 2-3 spaces.

You can choose to make fullscreen in whichever monitor you want, probably one that's not your main. You have to keep the app on the external monitor fullscreen in order for the other monitors to have thumbnail spaces previews.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, but I just hope I can help someone else by sharing.

I am using a simple combination of [cliclick](https://github.com/BlueM/cliclick) and [skhd](https://github.com/koekeishiya/skhd). `cliclick` is able to manipulate mouse cursor, while skhd is able to send arbitrary shell commands with keyboard shortcuts.

Note that my setup is for something who does not use a mouse. I use `yabai` and `skhdrc` to minimize the dependency of using a mouse.

The steps are:

1. Set hot corner to Mission control[image: mission control screenshot]
2. Install [cliclick](https://github.com/BlueM/cliclick) and [skhd](https://github.com/koekeishiya/skhd) using `homebrew`
3. Map a keyboard shortcut that moves your mouse to a corner in `~/.skhdrc`:

```
# 0,0 represents the mouse coordinates
shift + cmd - m : cliclick -r m:0,0
```

You can also refer to my [.skhdrc](https://github.com/sagittaros/dotfiles/blob/77be0a5566ed59be3297e718e947b557638db1a0/.skhdrc#L80)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [pjv's](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/220886/167372) and [Arctus' answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/212213/167372), I found the temporary mouse coordinate of (0,0) to not reliably trigger the spaces preview. Half of my display resolution on the x-axis and a little deviation on the y-axis are working fine, though. On my MacBook Air with a 1440x900 resolution, (720,25) is a robust setting.

Answer (score 0):

To throw another hat in the ring for [Better Touch Tool](https://www.boastr.net/), it looks like they now provide this action right out of the box:

1. Select Global Application
   [image: Select Global Application]
2. Select Touchpad Gesture
   [image: Select Touchpad Gesture]
3. Add a New Gesture
   [image: Add a New Gesture]
4. Select "3 Finger Swipe Up"
   [image: Select "3 Finger Swipe Up"]
5. Choose Predefined Action
   [image: Choose Predefined Action]
6. Search for "Mission Control & Immediately Show Desktop Preview"
   [image: Mission Control & Immediately Show Desktop Preview]
7. It should look like this at the end
   [image: Gesture Summary]
   [image: Gesture Fields]

Answer (score 0):

[missionControlFullDesktopBar](https://github.com/briankendall/missionControlFullDesktopBar) works great on High Sierra. I have it working with [Hammerspoon](https://www.hammerspoon.org/) to intercept Mission Control (F3) keypresses, video of it working [here](https://youtu.be/K0PgxgLWZM4), see [my full hammerspoon config here](https://github.com/skehlet/hammerspoon):

```
-- if missionControlFullDesktopBar installed, intercept Mission Control (F3) keypresses and launch it instead
-- See https://github.com/briankendall/missionControlFullDesktopBar
local MCFDB_PATH = '/Applications/missionControlFullDesktopBar.app/Contents/MacOS/missionControlFullDesktopBar'
local mcfdbSize = hs.fs.attributes(MCFDB_PATH, 'size')
if mcfdbSize then
    local MISSION_CONTROL_KEYCODE = 160
    local log = hs.logger.new('missionControlFullDesktopBar', 'debug')
    log.i('missionControlFullDesktopBar found, intercepting Mission Control key events')
    function handleMissionControl(e)
        local code = e:getProperty(hs.eventtap.event.properties.keyboardEventKeycode)
        if code == MISSION_CONTROL_KEYCODE then
            -- ignore auto-repeats
            local isAutoRepeat = e:getProperty(hs.eventtap.event.properties.keyboardEventAutorepeat)
            if isAutoRepeat == 1 then
                return true -- discard
            end
            -- don't intercept cmd+f3 or ctrl+f3
            local flags = e:getFlags()
            if (flags.cmd or flags.ctrl) then
                return false -- propogate
            end
            local type = e:getType()
            if type == hs.eventtap.event.types.keyDown then
                --log.i('intercepted Mission Control DOWN')
                os.execute(MCFDB_PATH..' -d -i')
                return true -- discard
            elseif type == hs.eventtap.event.types.keyUp then
                --log.i('intercepted Mission Control UP')
                os.execute(MCFDB_PATH..' -d -r')
                return true -- discard
            end
        end
        return false -- propogate
    end
    trapMissionControl = hs.eventtap.new({hs.eventtap.event.types.keyDown, hs.eventtap.event.types.keyUp}, handleMissionControl)
    trapMissionControl:start()
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any in-built solution but I use BetterTouchTool for this.
Newer version of *BetterTouchTool* has an option to **Mission Control & Immediately Show Desktop Preview** which does exactly what you asked for.[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer free solution, expecially you would like to use karabiner, here is a method worth trying.

[cliclick](https://github.com/BlueM/cliclick) is needed. It's not elegant enough but just ok to use.

```json
{
    "description": "Double RCmd/ROpt to Open Mission Control / Expose",
    "manipulators": [
        {
            "description": "Double RCmd to Open Mission Control",
            "conditions": [
                {
                    "name": "rcmd_double",
                    "type": "variable_if",
                    "value": 1
                }
            ],
            "from": {
                "key_code": "right_command"
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "key_code": "mission_control"
                },
                {
                    "shell_command": "cliclick=/opt/homebrew/bin/cliclick; curpos=$($cliclick p); $cliclick m:0,0; sleep 0.1; $cliclick m:1,1; $cliclick m:${curpos}"
                }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
        },
        {
            "description": "Double RCmd to Open Mission Control (condition)",
            "from": {
                 "key_code": "right_command",
                 "modifiers": {
                     "mandatory": [],
                         "optional": []
                 }
            },
            "parameters": {
                 "basic.simultaneous_threshold_milliseconds": 500
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "set_variable": {
                        "name": "rcmd_double",
                        "value": 1
                    }
                },
                { 
                    "key_code": "right_command"
                }
             ],
             "to_delayed_action": {
                 "to_if_invoked": [
                     {
                         "set_variable": {
                             "name": "rcmd_double",
                             "value": 0
                         }
                     }
                 ],
             "to_if_canceled": [
                 {
                     "set_variable": {
                     "name": "rcmd_double",
                      "value": 0
                     }
                 }
             ]
        },
        "type": "basic"
    ]
}
```